# How to get value of input text field without knowing its id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have created a javascript script in which all clicks and action of a particular IP it tracked down when attached in a page. It all works fine except when **the user searches something from an input field**. I need to track that text which user has searched.

> But I don't have any information regarding that input field i.e **id or class** also a page can have.
>   **multiple input fields** i.e A form for submission too.

I need to get that text when the **enter key is pressed or any button(search) is pressed**

In my case at present html page, I have below code.

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <!-- Search Page -->
  <div id="search-container" class="search-container" style="float: left;">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
      <div class="search-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="search-layouts-input" ng-model="searchQuery" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="So, what are you looking for?" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? actionSearch() : null">
        <button type="submit" class="s-layout-btn" ng-click="actionSearch();">
          <svg id="Layer_1" width="20px" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#222">
            <defs>
              <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#222;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2px;}</style>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Search Page -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some example html ?

Comment: you can use comething like `$('.header > div > div > div > input')` to find your input without class or id

Comment: @Goran.it take any site with search feature as an example

Comment: okay @20yco let me try this one

Comment: @20yco didn't work... I guess because of .header class..page didn't have such class .. I can't depend on header class :(

Comment: @PriyankaSharma of course, because header class i get from my mind, can you show us some html code of your project?

Comment: @20yco sir..i have attached that part with my question..but I need to test it on other html pages..on other sites..where I don't know how many input fields will be present.

Comment: @PriyankaSharma try `$('.search-input-wrapper > input')` as selector

Comment: @20yco I will not know class name of that div...means, in this case, yes I know..but I want to get the text of input on other's html too ..my main aim is to get that text by $(input) something

Comment: @PriyankaSharma ohh..other htmls... you need to use function with regex or something like a filter to find inputs on the page with predefined words like 'search / input[type="text"]', in your case it's not so easy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186358/discussion-between-priyanka-sharma-and-20yco).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing that you're looking to implement? Of course most of it is pseudo code, but it's pretty straight-forward, just get all relevant inputs and buttons and whatnot, attach some event handler to them and update the application state.

I've included some basic functions that you may wish to fire in certain scenarios, such as `onStateUpdate`, there may be no **need** for this function, but it probably wouldn't hurt to keep it for the sake of simplcity.

I've used mostly ES6 oriented syntax because it allows you to achieve the same results with less code, I'm just *that* lazy.

The reason why I used a self invoked function just so there's no issues with variable names and nothing can be manipulated on the global scope, etc. If you'd like to read or know more about why self invoked functions can be pretty good, then I suggest you read sources such as [this](https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```js
// Self invoked anonymous function. 
(function() {
  // The application state.
  const state = {};

  // Lazy way to use querySelectorAll
  const $e = qs => document.querySelectorAll(qs);

  // Make a copy of the state and make it global.
  const getState = () => {
    window.state = { ...state};
    console.clear();
    console.log(window.state);
  };

  // A function to run when the state updates.
  const onStateUpdate = () => {
    // Do some other stuff... 
    getState();
  };

  // Handle the key up event.
  const inputHandler = (i, index) => i.onkeyup = () => {
    i.id == null || i.id == '' ? i.setAttribute("id", index) : null;
    const id = i.id;
    state[id] = i.value;
    onStateUpdate();
  };

  // Handle a button being clicked.
  const clickHandler = btn => btn.onclick = onStateUpdate;

  // Handle the enter key being pressed.
  const enterHandler = e => e.keyCode == 13 ? onStateUpdate() : null;

  // Assign all relevant events to the relevant functions. 
  const dispatchEvents = () => {
    const inputs = $e("#search-container input[type=text]");
    const buttons = $e("#search-container button");

    inputs.forEach((i, index) => inputHandler(i, index));
    buttons.forEach(b => clickHandler(b));
    window.onkeypress = enterHandler;
  };

  // Fire the dispatch function. 
  dispatchEvents();
}());
```

```html
<!-- this one does nothing as it's outside of the search-container element -->
<input type="text" id="testing" placeholder="I do nothing!" />

<div id="search-container">
  <input type="text" id="test" />
  <input type="text" id="demo" />
  <input type="text" id="markup" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

### Older Syntax

```js
// Self invoked anonymous function. 
(function() {
  // The application state.
  var state = {};

  // Lazy way to use querySelectorAll
  var $e = function(qs) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(qs);
  };

  // Make a copy of the state and make it global.
  var getState = function() {
    window.state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    console.clear();
    console.log(window.state);
  };

  // A function to run when the state updates.
  var onStateUpdate = function() {
    // Do some other stuff... 
    getState();
  };

  // Handle the key up event.
  var inputHandler = function(i, index) {
    i.onkeyup = function() {


      if (i.id == null || i.id == '') {
        i.setAttribute("id", index);
      }

      var id = i.id;
      state[id] = i.value;
      onStateUpdate();
    };
  };

  // Handle a button being clicked.
  var clickHandler = function(btn) {
    btn.onclick = onStateUpdate;
  };

  // Handle the enter key being pressed.
  var enterHandler = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      onStateUpdate();
    };
  };

  // Assign all relevant events to the relevant functions. 
  var dispatchEvents = function() {
    var inputs = $e("input[type=text]");
    var buttons = $e("button");

    inputs.forEach(function(i, index) {
      inputHandler(i, index)
    });

    buttons.forEach(function(b) {
      clickHandler(b)
    });

    window.onkeypress = enterHandler;
  };

  // Fire the dispatch function. 
  dispatchEvents();
}());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" />
<input type="text" id="demo" />
<input type="text" id="markup" />
<input type="text" />
<button>Search</button>
```

Comment: i can't understand the code :( also now working on my html

Comment: @PriyankaSharma Would you like to see an ES5 implementation? :) I take it you're very new to JavaScript? It's simple, I promise!

Comment: yep ..that would be a great help:)! and not a newbie but I work on old format my as my project is in same :( I know ES6 is smart and easy but a bit complex for me ;) for now!

Comment: @PriyankaSharma I've made an update using more legacy friendly syntax, no arrow functions, not object destructuring, no use of constants, etc! I hope this helps!

Comment: search-container class??  I won't have any information about input field div..you know that right ;)?

Comment: @PriyankaSharma I'm no using any form of class, I used an ID, sure, but either way, just remove `#search-container` like I've done in my most recent edit?! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186392/discussion-between-priyanka-sharma-and-jo3-w3b-d3v).